# React Native Navigation inside Map Function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to generate a Card from JSON data using Map function in React Native.

I want to be able to navigate to another page by clicking on this card.

This is the solution I am trying:

```js
function display() {
  
  return restaurant.map((item) => {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Restaurant')}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.cardHeadText}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              { item.name }
            </Text>
            <Text>
              { item.type }
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  });
}

class RestaurantCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {display()}
      </View>
      
      
    );
  }
}
```

But I get following error:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Taking a real blind stab here but just under `function display()` put something like `const that = this`, then change your onPress to `that.props.navi....`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` as an argument to the `map` function as described in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
function display() {
  
  return restaurant.map((item) => {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Restaurant')}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.cardHeadText}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              { item.name }
            </Text>
            <Text>
              { item.type }
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }, this); // over here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :)
Ive passed navigation as a props in display function, destructing it and re-using as a short curt to acess this.props.navigation..

Extracting the logic of the click in a `handler` made it easy to read and control, you can add verifies and other things a lot more easier.

```js
function display(props) {
  const { navigation } = props

  const handlerClick = (item) => {
      /*
         all the content of item (name, and type) will be passed in
         props of the other page component
      */
      navigation.navigate("Restaurant", { ...item})
  }

  return restaurant.map((item) => {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => handlerClick(item)}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.cardHeadText}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
              { item.name }
            </Text>
            <Text>
              { item.type }
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  });
}

class RestaurantCard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {display(this.props.navigation)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```